# android rule engine

Tags: java, android, rule-engine

Are there any open source java rules engines that could run in android?  By open I mean open like BSD.

Comment: You should elaborate on "open like BSD."  BSD is what's called a permissive open source license.  However, there are a great many other [open source licenses](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/index.html) with varying rules.

Answer (score -3):

Also, a google search can be helpful: http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines

Comment: To be fair, the author was asking specifically about rule engines that run on Android.  I've enjoyed working with Drools (one of the engines in the list you gave the link for) but I've read that it isn't Android friendly.